# Multiple rows into one line, when there's a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to get a list of all Activities in our system. An Activity can have 1:many service providers who manage the activity - so I have an Ativity table, with a many to many linking table (ActivityServiceProvider) and a list of Service providers.

A query to get the data looks like this.

```
SELECT a.id, sp.Description
FROM Activity a
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityServiceProvider asp
    ON asp.ActivityID = a.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceProvider sp
    ON sp.ID = asp.ServiceProviderID
```

But as there might be more than one service provider per activity, I need to somehow use STUFF to get the list of Service Providers into a single row column.

I tried this, but it's failing with jsut a single row being returned:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((
        SELECT a.ID, ', ' + MAX(sp.Description) 
        FROM Activity a
        INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityServiceProvider asp
            ON asp.ActivityID = a.ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceProvider sp
            ON sp.ID = asp.ServiceProviderID
        GROUP BY a.ID 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,2,'') AS NameValues
```

Can anyone spot the issue? The 'STUFF' and FOR XML keyword confuses me, so I might be making a basic error, but I am trying to return an ActivityID, and a ServiceProviders column, with a comma separated list of Service Providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an outer query to fetch each activity.  Then the subquery combines the results for each description.  There is no need for aggregation in the subquery -- the `FOR XML PATH()` takes care of that:

```
SELECT a.*,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sp.Description
              FROM dbo.ActivityServiceProvider asp INNER JOIN
                   dbo.ServiceProvider sp
                   ON sp.ID = asp.ServiceProviderID
              WHERE asp.ActivityID = a.ID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
                    ), 1, 2, ''
            ) AS NameValues
FROM activity a;
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I need to work out why, but  - wow. Thanks.